# Blazor WASM Lazy Loaded Assemblies Service Registration for Dependency Injection

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a lazy loaded assembly that contains services that I need to register with the built in Dependency Injection implementation. How do I register these services so I can inject them as dependencies through the normal injection mechanism, into components that the lazy loaded assembly contains.

Comment: Can you add some code examples? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that would be helpfull.

https://blogs.u2u.be/peter/post/blazor-lazy-loading-and-dependency-injection

*To save it for later the essence of it:*

### Lazy Loading and Dependency Injection

Start by creating a new library project (in my code called LazyLoaded). Next add a class LazyLoadedWeatherForecastService that will function as a **Factory:**

```
public class LazyLoadedWeatherForecastService
{
  private readonly IServiceProvider services;

  public LazyLoadedWeatherForecastService(IServiceProvider services)
  {
    this.services = services;
  }

  public IWeatherForecastService Create()
  {
    HttpClient http = this.services.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
    return new WeatherForecastService(http);
  }
}
```

Now add a reference to this project

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\LazyLoaded\LazyLoaded.csproj" />
```

Replace the dependency in your Program.cs

```
// builder.Services.AddScoped<IWeatherForecastService, WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<LazyLoadedWeatherForecastService>();
```

Replace the IWeatherForecastService dependency with the factory class:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@inject LazyLoaded.LazyLoadedWeatherForecastService factory
```

And use it to create the actual dependency

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  forecasts = await factory.Create().GetWeatherForecasts();
}
```